# How to stop text in div pushing other divs down the page?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want to align the text in my div ('what' and 'where') but now that I have the text a the bottom it has pushed the divs (search-field1 and searchfield2) further down the page!

How can I have it so the text doesnt affect this? Is it something to do with the cellpadding/spacing?

Sorry im not the best at CSS I'm teaching myself it.

HTML:

```
<center>
<div class="what"><p>what?</div>
<div class="where">where?</div>
<div>
</center>

<center>
<div class="search-field1">

</div>
<div class="search-field2">

</div>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.what{
display: inline;
font: 16px HelveticaNeue-Light;
color: #A9E2F3;
font-weight: bold;
height: 35px;
width: 320px;
background: #151515;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: center;


}

.where{
display: inline;
font: 16px HelveticaNeue-Light;
color: #A9E2F3;
font-weight: bold;
height: 35px;
width: 320px;
background: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
verticle-align: center;

}

.search-field1{
height: 35px;
width: 320px;
background: #ffffff;
border:1px solid;
border-color: #BDBDBD;
display: inline-block;
verticle-align: center;
}

.search-field2{
height: 35px;
width: 320px;
background: #ffffff;
border:1px solid;
border-color: #BDBDBD;
display: inline-block;
horizontal-align: center;
}
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: double check your html, you have a rogue <p> tag

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net with your code in to show the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is James. Can you explain it in clearer terms? You should really avoid use of the `center` tag if possible and use the CSS `text-align: center;` property instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, i removed the <p>. All i really need now is to know how to align the text 'what' and 'where' at the bottom of the div. How is this done? I have researched t but it doesnt seem to affect my code

Comment: It will be great if you could draw the div as you needed and post here. So others have a idea about what you need

Comment: Basically how do you put text at the bottom of a div?

Comment: first: horizontal-align will not be affect the divs. If you using tables it will work. Otherwise you should use any of the tags eg. H1, H1 may be P to take your text to bottom. Without using those you will only be able to postion the text using text-align property

Comment: Ah thanks so how is the H1 tag used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

James is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/WFPK2/

Set the line-height for your containers (in this case `.what` and `.where` to be the same as the height:

```
line-height: 35px;
```

Comment: This works as long as the height of both div's contents are the same. (I am still searching) Tested in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need `float:left` on your `center` tags

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="what">what?</div>
    <div class="where">where?</div>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <div class="search-field1"></div>
    <div class="search-field2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:
If you use `float:left` on the enclosing div's it will allow the two `center` div's to float side by side.

```
.center {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set your line height to zero on the hidden div like so:

```
    line-height: 0px;
```

Then add padding to the surrounding divs. Like so:

```
    padding-top: 10px;
```

Hope that helps someone.